# changing background color of Blackberry ButtonField

Tags: blackberry, jde

I wanted to change the background color of ButtonField in black berry jde 6, by overriding 
the paint method, but not able to change whole background of the ButtonField

Answer (score 4):

I solved this problem by extending the `Field` class. Here is my version. Hope it helps.

```
/**
 * ColorButtonField is a custom button field that creates buttons of a specified 
 * size and color.
 */

import net.rim.device.api.system.Display;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Color;  
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Field;  
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Font;  
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Graphics;  
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Keypad;

public class ColorButtonField extends Field  
{  

private int backgroundColour;  
private int highlightColour;
private int colour;
private int fieldWidth;  
private int fieldHeight;  
private String text;  
private int padding = 8;  
private double fontWidth;
private Font font;

public ColorButtonField(String text, int highlightColour, int backgroundColour)  
{  
    super();  
    this.text = text;  
    this.highlightColour = highlightColour;
    this.backgroundColour = backgroundColour;
    colour = backgroundColour;

    font = Font.getDefault();  
    fieldHeight = font.getHeight() + padding;
    fontWidth = font.getHeight() / 2;
    fieldWidth = (Display.getWidth() - 12) / 3;  
    this.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);  
} 

public ColorButtonField(String text, int highlightColour, int backgroundColour, int width, int height, int padding)  
{  
    super();  
    this.text = text;  
    this.highlightColour = highlightColour;
    this.backgroundColour = backgroundColour;
    colour = backgroundColour;
    font = Font.getDefault();  
    fieldHeight = height;  
    fieldWidth = width;  
    this.setPadding(2, padding, 2, padding);  
} 
public void setFont(Font font){
    this.font = font;
}
public void setFocus(){
    super.setFocus();
}
public boolean isFocusable(){
    return true;
}

protected boolean keyChar(char character, int status, int time) {
     if (character == Keypad.KEY_ENTER) {
     fieldChangeNotify(0);
     return true;
     }
     return super.keyChar(character, status, time);
 }
protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time)  
{  
    fieldChangeNotify(0);  
    return true;  
}  

protected void onFocus(int direction)  
{  
    colour = highlightColour;  
    invalidate();  
}  

protected void onUnfocus()  
{  
    colour = backgroundColour;  
    invalidate();  
}  

public int getPreferredWidth()  
{  
    return fieldWidth;  
}  

public int getPreferredHeight()  
{  
    return fieldHeight;  
}  

protected void layout(int arg0, int arg1)  
{  
    setExtent(getPreferredWidth(), getPreferredHeight());  
}  

protected void drawFocus(Graphics graphics, boolean on)  
{  

}  

protected void fieldChangeNotify(int context)  
{  
    try  
    {  
        this.getChangeListener().fieldChanged(this, context);  
    }  
    catch (Exception e)  
    {}  
}  

protected void paint(Graphics graphics)  
{  
    graphics.setColor(colour);  
    graphics.fillRoundRect(0, 0, fieldWidth, fieldHeight, 8, 8);  
    graphics.setColor(colour + 0x333333);  
    graphics.drawRoundRect(0, 0, fieldWidth, fieldHeight, 8, 8);  
    graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE); 
    if( 0 < text.indexOf(' ')){
      graphics.drawText(text.substring(0, text.indexOf(' ') ), fieldWidth / 2 - font.getAdvance(text.substring(0, text.indexOf(' ') )) / 2 , 5);
      graphics.drawText(text.substring(text.indexOf(' ') + 1), fieldWidth / 2 - font.getAdvance(text.substring(text.indexOf(' ') + 1)) / 2 , fieldHeight / 2);
    }
    else
    graphics.drawText(text, fieldWidth / 2 - font.getAdvance(text) / 2 , fieldHeight / 2 - 10);  
}  
}
```

Comment: Good example, but I would suggest using getFont().getAdvance(text) to determine the width of the button.

Answer (score 1):

try adding

```
protected void applyTheme()
{
}
```

It will remove borders/themes

Answer (score 0):

This code helps you:

```
ButtonField save=new ButtonField("Save",FIELD_HCENTER);     
save.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.GREEN));
Border border=BorderFactory.createRoundedBorder(new XYEdges(2,2,2,2));
save.setBorder(border); 
add(save);
```

Here **XYEdges(2,2,2,2)** is the Border for that Button.